# Why is $O(n^3)$ = $\Theta(n^2)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I have a problem

$T(n) = 9T(n/3) + O(n^3)$

Answer is by Master's Theorem, second case (based on CLRS), so 
$T(n) = \Theta(n^3\log n)$

But this implies $O(n^3) = \Theta(n^2)$, how can this be true if the function bounded by $O(n^3)$ is $n^3$?

Comment: The solution to this recurrence is $\Theta(n^3)$ (third case), not $\Theta(n^3\log n)$.

Comment: Thank you, I suspect that the solution that I have is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

(Oops - I wrote
$O(n^3)$ when the OP wrote
$O(n^2)$.
It's even truer.)

If $T(n) = \Theta(n^3\log n)$,
then it is *not* true that
$T(n) = O(n^3)$.

$T(n) = \Theta(n^3\log n)$
means that
there are positive constants
$a$ and $b$ such that,
for all large enough $n$,
$a n^3 \log n
< T(n)
<b n^3 \log n
$.

The first inequality shows that
$T(n)$ is too large
for it to satisfy
$T(n) = O(n^3)$.